# how to set field in constructor in java

Tags: java, object, methods, constructor

there are 3 fields in constructor( name , points ,weapon ) and they are stored in arrayList and I want to modify name from another method..how can I do this?
and what is the meaning of passing "this" keyword as parameter..
I am new in java programming

i used below code to update name and its changing name but points becomes 0 and and weapon "null"

```
public void modify(String name) {
    if(savedValues!= null && savedValues.size()>0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < savedValues.size(); i++) {
            if (savedValues.get(i).getName().equals(name)) {
                System.out.println("enter new name");
                Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
                //this.name = scanner.next();
                savedValues.set(i,this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: Hi vinS.. thanks for reply..

Comment: `this` is a java keyword that denotes context. If you have an object `Bar` with a field `foo`, but at some point you pass in an argument also called `foo`, `this` clarifies which `foo` you're talking about. `this.foo` refers to the `foo` defined in `Bar` (declared as `int foo;` or something like that), as opposed to the `foo` supplied as an argument. If you were to pass `this` from `Bar` to a second object `Baz` by calling a method belonging to `Baz` from `Bar`, however, you're passing a reference to `Bar` into `Baz`. Now you can call methods of `Bar` from `Baz`.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, please list the entire class file. We need to at least see the constructor and the property fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify an array passed as a method-parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129369/modify-an-array-passed-as-a-method-parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
String newName = scanner.next();
savedValues.get(i).setName(newName);
```

`savedValues.get(i)` will give you an object and you are trying to update the name property of that particular object. this is a reference to the object instance in which your code is running. It does not make sense to use this here.

Comment: thank you very much...solved

Comment: Good to know. In addition to accept answer you can up vote it too :)